# What are macros?

Tags: objective-c, macros

I'm not sure what macros are. For example the following macro is found in the cocos2d framework written in objective-c. What exactly is a macro,why are they useful, and how do I define them? Thanks.

```
#define CCRANDOM_0_1() ((random() / (float)0x7fffffff ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you'll find everything you need:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

But to get a basic idea, they are pieces of code that replace the macro name when you write them in your code.

In your example, if you wrote:

```
int i = CCRANDOM_0_1();
```

It would be the same as:

```
int i =  ((random() / (float)0x7fffffff ));
```

Comment: So, this example is a way of generating a random number. I guess since it's done often enough it's useful to write it as a shortcut like this?

Comment: Yes, for two reasons. First to avoid duplicating this code every time you need a random number, and second to avoid overhead by calling a non-inline function.

Comment: @Victor: How do you set the range? for e.g. 0 - 15

Answer (score 2):

it just replace`CCRANDOM_0_1()` with `((random() / (float)0x7fffffff ))` in your code

Answer (score 1):

Whenever `CCRANDOM+0_1()` is seen in the program (by the compiler) it will be replaced by `((random() / (float)0x7fffffff ))`